# Prove that there exists a function $f$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: (f(x))^5 + 5 f(x) + \sin(f(x)) = x$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that there exists a function $f$ such that
>
> $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: (f(x))^5 + 5 f(x) + \sin(f(x)) = x$$

I've been trying to use inverse theorem or using the derivative and can't get anything out of it.

Comment: Consider the function $g(t)=t^5+5t+\sin t$, then $g'(t)=5t^4+5+\cos t\ge 0+5-1=4>0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, so $g$ is strictly increasing and therefore 1-1 on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I was able to get there myself but I might be missing some knowledge for understanding the implication. What if f(t) /= t, how can you be sure g'(t) > 0 for all t. If a function is one to one then it's enough of an argument to prove that such function exists to describe said above equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant and quickest way is that based on the comment by @Alexander Burstein.

Here are two other ways based on your ideas:

Using **implicit function theorem** (which boils down to above mentioned comment):
$$F(x,y) = y^5+5y+\sin y - x = 0 $$ 
satisfies the assumtions of the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem):
$$\partial_yF(x,y) = 5y^4+5+\cos y > 0$$
For any $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}$ with $F(x_0,y_0)$ the equation is invertible, which means it defines a function $y=f(x)$ in an open neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$.

Using **derivatives**:
Just assuming $y$ is differentiable, we get 
$$5y^4y' + 5y'+\cos{(y)}y' - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow y' =\frac{1}{5y^4+5+\cos y}$$
For any $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}$ with $F(x_0,y_0)$ we have an initial value problem
$$y'(x)=g(x,y(x))= \frac{1}{5y^4+5+\cos y}, \; y(x_0) = y_0$$
Function $g$ satisfies the assumptions of the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), as $g$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $y$, because $g'$ is bounded.
So, we get the existence of the function looked for.

In both cases you get the unique function $f(x)$ **locally**.
You may reason for yourself why these local functions represent "snippets" of a global $f(x)$.